# Pass Spring Batch Tasklet Failure Message to Reporting Step.

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using a Spring Batch Tasklet with OpenCSV to read my CSV files. Before the question is asked, I'm aware of chunks, but there is cross validation between files in a later step, so I must continue to use the Tasklet.

What I'm trying to do is report a missing file or parsing error to my reporting step. I'm not sure what the proper approach should be to report the failure to my next step. I have the following code.

**Initial step to read file.**

```
public class CsvBatchReader<T> implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CsvBatchReader.class);

    private List batch;

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    private Path path;

    public CsvBatchReader(Class<T> clazz, Path path) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("Reader initialized - " + clazz.getSimpleName());

        batch = new ArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("Reader ended - " + clazz.getSimpleName());
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws UnexpectedJobExecutionException {
        logger.info("Reader execute - " + clazz.getSimpleName());


        ICsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBean(clazz, path);

        try {
            batch = csvToBean.readCsv();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            // error message being caught from my csvToBean class. 
            throw new UnexpectedJobExecutionException("Invalid file " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

**Reporting Step**

I'm not sure how to pass in the exception message or if there is defined method to passing in the failure message without using the Step Execution Context.

```
public class CsvBatchReporting implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CsvBatchCrossValidation.class);

    private List errorMessages;
    private List skippedInserts;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("Reporting initialized");

        ExecutionContext executionContext = stepExecution
                .getJobExecution()
                .getExecutionContext();

        System.out.println("description " + stepExecution.getStatus());


    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        logger.info("Reporting ended");
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Reporting execute");

        //Email Error 

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

}
```

**Job Config**

```
@Bean
public Job primaryCareJob(@Qualifier("reportingStep") Step reportingStep, @Qualifier("crossValidationStep") Step crossValidationStep) {
    logger.info("Start PrimaryCare Job");

    return jobs.get("primaryCareJob")
            .start(readPrimaryCareStep()).on("FAILED").to(reportingStep)
            .from(readPrimaryCareStep()).on("*").to(readPrimaryCareDetailStep())

            .from(readPrimaryCareDetailStep()).on("FAILED").to(reportingStep)
            .from(readPrimaryCareDetailStep()).on("*").to(processPrimaryCareStep())

            .from(processPrimaryCareStep()).on("INVALID").to(reportingStep)
            .from(processPrimaryCareStep()).on("*").to(processPrimaryCareDetailStep())

            .from(processPrimaryCareDetailStep()).on("INVALID").to(reportingStep)
            //Other steps

            .from(reportingStep).on("*").end()
            .from(reportingStep).on("*").fail()

            .build()
        .build();
}
```

I started changing my job pattern to fail rather than defining it as invalid to get the exception to automatically call the failed step. Other steps where I'm using invalid are being defined in my afterStep using the following code.

```
if(!errorMessages.isEmpty()) {
            chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("INVALID"));
}
```

How do I get the CSV exception message from reader to be passed into my reporting step so that I can send it as an email?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to pass in the exception message or if there is defined method to passing in the failure message without using the Step Execution Context.

You can get access to the exception thrown in a previous step from the job execution. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return steps.get("step1")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    throw new Exception("Boom!");
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step2() {
        return steps.get("step2")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    JobExecution jobExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution();
                    StepExecution stepExecution = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().iterator().next(); // TODO properly get the stepExecution of the previous step
                    List<Throwable> failureExceptions = stepExecution.getFailureExceptions();
                    if (!failureExceptions.isEmpty()) {
                        Throwable throwable = failureExceptions.get(0);
                        System.out.println("Looks like step1 has thrown an exception: " + throwable.getMessage());
                    }
                    System.out.println("world");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                    .flow(step1())
                    .on("*").to(step2())
                    .build()
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

}
```

This sample prints:

```
hello
Looks like step1 has thrown an exception: Boom!
world
```

Obviously, you need to make sure step1 flows to step2 in all cases (Hence the flow definition).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll have to read up on the flow definition as I'm not sure what the difference is between what I'm doing with .start(readPrimaryCareStep()).on("FAILED").to(reportingStep) vs flow()... As long as my previous step is the one to throw the exception, would it be safe to assume the stepExecutions().iterator will always get the previous step first?

Comment: As said in the code comment, you need to properly get the step execution of the previous step. Once you get all step executions with `jobExecution.getStepExecutions()`, you can for example iterate through it and filter by name the step you want.

Comment: Okay, I just wasn't sure if it was first in first out. Generally if I'm failing the job like this I'm going to go right the reporting step and get the previous step that failed. I wasn't sure if there was an actual need to iterate and filter the steps if the iterator would just get me the previous step. Anyhow thanks for the incite, this definitely makes things simpler.

Comment: as an alternative to throwing exceptions, I discovered the ability to use exitStatus codes and descriptions. I provided an alternative answer to throwing exceptions using the exitStatus. Considering you are one of the SpringBatch engineers, would you mind commenting on the answer? I would be interested in knowing whether or not it's best to throw exceptions or create existStatus objects.

Comment: I added a comment on your alternative answer as requested. I'd be happy to help if you need further support.

Answer (score 3):

Consider making `errorMessages` a bean:

```
// somewhere convenient...
@Bean
public List<String> errorMessages() {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and inject `errorMessages` into both tasklets.

In the `CsvBatchReader` tasklet, inspect for any exceptions thrown by `execute(...)`, and update `errorMessages` as needed:

```
public class CsvBatchReader<T> implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        List<Throwable> failures = stepExecution.getFailureExceptions();
        if (!failures.isEmpty())  {
            errorMessages.add(...);
        }

        logger.info("Reader ended - " + clazz.getSimpleName());
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;  // return INVALID if !failures.isEmpty() ?
    }
}
```

And since `errorMessages` was injected into `CsvBatchReporting`, then:

```
public class CsvBatchReporting implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Reporting execute");

    //Email Error 
    String body = null;
    String subject = "job finished: ";
    if (!errorMessages.isEmpty())  {
       subject += "ERROR";
       body = ... // from errorMessages
    } else {
       subject += "SUCCESS";
    }

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}

}
```

Comment: Would creating a errorMessages bean be thread safe if running parallel jobs which both use the same bean? I wasn't aware of the stepExecution.getFailureExceptions, would it be more advisable to put the error messages from the failure in the executionContext with a key and later pull it back? Example stepExecution
                .getJobExecution()
                .getExecutionContext()
                .put(key, failures ); Or would you still Inject the error message bean?

Comment: It would not be thread safe if running parallel jobs and steps were sharing the bean.  Using the context is the [documented approach](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps).

Comment: check out Mahmoud Ben Hassine answer below, seems like the best way to retrieve exceptions in later steps without having to store them in a bean or the context.

Comment: Yes - agreed - that would be easier!

Answer (score 3):

Although my original question was in reference to passing exceptions from one step to the next, I would like to point out an alternative approach using `exitStatus`

In my reader step I can catch my csvToBean exception and create an exist status like so.

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws UnexpectedJobExecutionException {
    logger.info("Reader execute - " + clazz.getSimpleName());

    ICsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBean(clazz, path);

    try {
        batch = csvToBean.readCsv();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("FAILED", ex.getMessage()));
    }

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

I would then create conditional flow with in my job like so.

```
@Bean
public Job primaryCareJob(@Qualifier("reportingStep") Step reportingStep, @Qualifier("crossValidationStep") Step crossValidationStep) {
    logger.info("Start PrimaryCare Job");

    return jobs.get("primaryCareJob")
            .start(readPrimaryCareStep()).on("FAILED").to(reportingStep)
            .from(readPrimaryCareStep()).on("*").to(readPrimaryCareDetailStep())

            .from(readPrimaryCareDetailStep()).on("FAILED").to(reportingStep)
            .from(readPrimaryCareDetailStep()).on("*").to(processPrimaryCareStep())

            .from(processPrimaryCareStep()).on("INVALID").to(reportingStep)
            .from(processPrimaryCareStep()).on("*").to(processPrimaryCareDetailStep())

            .from(processPrimaryCareDetailStep()).on("INVALID").to(reportingStep)
            //Other steps

            .from(reportingStep).on("*").end()
            .from(reportingStep).on("*").fail()

            .build()
        .build();
}
```

Lastly in my reader tasklet step I would retrieve the existStatus like so

```
@Override
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    JobExecution jobExecution = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution();

    Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions();

    Map<String, String> result = stepExecutions.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals("FAILED"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(StepExecution::getStepName, x -> x.getExitStatus().getExitDescription()));

    result.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println("Step " + k + " failure " + v);
    });
}
```

Comment: As you said, the original question was about passing the exception instance itself. But using the ExitStatus would work if you only need the exception message. I'm always in favor of the least powerful solution that would work, so if you need only the exception message, you can definitely use the ExitStatus approach.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine I'll be attending your session on Thursday, I look forward to it.

Comment: Ohh great! Please pass by and say hi!

Comment: Hey @CodeJunkie Thank you for coming to the session at Spring One! It was nice meeting you. I hope you enjoyed the content.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine it was great, I learned a lot from the session. Thank you so much for all your hard work.